# Using same DB9 port for RS232 and RS485 (selectable) - looking for IC

Tags: rs232, rs485, transceiver

Do any of you know of any transceiver ICs that can switch between RS232 and full or half duplex RS485? I'd like to be able to select which type of communication is used with either a jumper or input pin.

Basically I just want to have a port than can toggle between RS232/RS485 to give the user more flexibility since I'm limited on UARTs.

Comment: Where would 485 direction control come from - is the uart set up for that function? If yes, what about having a 232 port and a 485 port as separate hardware items?

Comment: I would like that to be part of the IC controlled with a direction pin from the MCU. Also, it needs to support full duplex RS485. Having two separate ports is not really an option... I only have 1 UART to use for both of these functions but they don't need to run at the same time - it will either be in RS485 or RS232 mode at any one time.

Comment: Many drivers have enable lines, so your actual problem may be figuring out which (on the logic side) gets to drive the MCU rx pin.  If those do not have enables, you can use a small multiplexor.

Comment: @Pugz - what I'm suggesting is two chips, one for 485 and 1 for 232 but different port sockets - can you accept a solution with a 232 port socket and a 485 port socket but only one will have full functionality depending on which is selected from the input pin or jumper.

Comment: I gotcha. That would work, but I'm also limited on layout space so they really need to go to the same DB9 port. How would you suggest making the jumper enable one and disable the other? Tying it to a force off or force on on one chip and inverting it for the other chip?

Comment: I guess this could be accomplished on one physical jack by picking ICs that tri-state the drivers/receivers when disabled? I'd really like to do this with one IC though if you are aware of any - mostly due to space on the layout.